# how to set cell width in javascript just after creating it with 'document.createElement()' method?

Tags: javascript, html

I've created cells for a dynamic table in html page using "document.createElement('td')" method & now wish to set width of each individual cell with some different value.
Tried "cell.width = width" but it didn't work.

how can I achieve it?

Comment: `cell.style.width = width`? Welcome to SO!

Comment: you want to change the width of the cell from the other corresponding cells in the table.

Comment: @SHANK: no...
actaully I'm adding cells to table dyanamically using some function in javascript & wish to add some code to set individual cell width right after I add a cell. :)

Comment: @11684: many thnx...... it workd...

Answer (score 12):

Use `style.width`:

```
var cell = document.createElement('td');
parent.appendChild(cell);
cell.style.width = '200px';
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvEDn/1/).

Comment: Click on the oldest tab :-)

Comment: Anyway, if +1 is so important here is one by me. Best regards! :-)

Answer (score 6):

To post my comment as an answer:

Use `cell.style.width = width;`.