# can't set td width in js-generated table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am generating a simple html-table and would like columns of different widths in the same row. However when I try to set the width either with pixels or with %, there is no change in the display. Also, the first column ('td' element) added is always much wider than other columns added later. I have tried setting the width after creating an element and before appending it as a child node as well as setting the width only after appending the element as a child node. Here is an example of what I have tried:

```
                    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                    tr.style.margin = "50px"

                    //scoring column
                    var td0 = document.createElement('TD')
                    td0.style.padding = '1em'
                    td0.style.width = '2px'

                    var tr11 = document.createElement('TR');
                    tr11.style.margin = "50px"
                    tr11.innerHTML ="score: " +  ascore_array[i + offset];

                    var tr22 = document.createElement('TR');
                    tr22.style.margin = "50px"
                    tr22.innerHTML ="num votes: " +  anumVotes_array[i + offset];

                    td0.appendChild(tr11)
                    td0.appendChild(tr22)


                    //answer column
                    var td1 = document.createElement('TD')
                    td1.style.padding = "1em"
                    td1.innerHTML =   auser_array[i + offset]

                    tr.appendChild(td0)
                    td0.style.width = "20%"
                    tr.appendChild(td1)
                    td1.style.width = "30%"
```

As you can see in the code above, I have tried both px and % as units of width. I have also tried setting the width both before and after setting an element as a child node. There is no change in my code. Also, I am using css templates, but they only set default background colors for my table elements. There is nothing in the css to regular td element sizing. Also I have tried resizing the tr elements within the td elements but this also has no effect.

I am using Chrome as my browser.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: where's your table element?

Comment: Can you post the outputted HTML code?

Comment: @atmd what I posted above is inside a for loop. The table element opens before the for loop and closes after.

Comment: @Fawn check the Elements tab in Chrome dev tools. That will get updated when you dynamically update the table

Comment: @cspete Thank you so much! I saw after you told me about this feature that there was a command further up setting the column widths of the table. Sorry to have troubled you, and I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I see what the problem is. There is a `<col style="width: 80%;">` and a `<col style="width: 20%;">` inbetween the root `<table>` and `<tbody>` which is overriding your styles in the `<td>` below

Comment: @Fawn I saw your comment just after I posted this! Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
var cell = document.createElement('td');
parent.appendChild(cell);
cell.style.width = '200px';
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/ZvEDn/1/ç](http://jsfiddle.net/ZvEDn/1/%C3%A7)

here is the question where i found it 
[how to set cell width in javascript just after creating it with 'document.createElement()' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14395420/how-to-set-cell-width-in-javascript-just-after-creating-it-with-document-create)